# setCustomValidity is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

This is the simple code I run hoping to get control over html5 validation but the browser says `setCustomvalidity` is not a function. what am I doing wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='text' id='tocheck' />
    <script>
        $("#tocheck").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.setCustomValidity("slkdjf");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my html5 ... I think

Answer (score 4):

jQuery does not have the `setCustomValidity` function, but the actual DOM element does. The jQuery selector always returns an Array, so you can use the zero index to get the actual DOM element or you can just use `this` (not `$(this)`) to get the DOM element upon which you can set the custom validity.

```html
 <!doctype html>

    <html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>


    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   </head>

  <body>
      <form>
      <input type='text' id='tocheck'/>
      <button>
      Submit
      </button>
      </form>
      <script>
       $("#tocheck").click(function(){
            this.setCustomValidity("slkdjf");
       });
     </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to

```
$this[0].setCustomValidity("slkdjf");
```

And html

```
<form> 
    <input type="text" id="tocheck">
    <button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You must use HTMLSelectElement not Jquery Element.
Does this code work ?

Comment: it does not show the error message in browswer console. but I expected the validation message to appear but nothing is shown.

Comment: Your new message will works inside <form></form> when you will press submit

Comment: I have been using it in click event of submit button but I am doing validation there and want to show the message from there and cancel submit. here I have shown a simple portion of it

Comment: Show you code validation and when you set setCustomValidity in it.

Comment: okay thanks.. i have got it.. reportvalidity is what I was asking about..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `this.setCustomValidity("slkdjf");` `this` is the DOM object, whereas `$(this)` is the jQuery wrapper around same.

```js
$("#tocheck").click(function(){
  this.setCustomValidity("slkdjf");
  $( "<p>slkdjf</p>" ).insertAfter( this );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='tocheck'/>
```

Comment: ok it does not give error message as before. but I expect the validation message to appear which does not show, when I click on the input element

Comment: @azamkhan you need to remove the mouse from input and rehover on it

Comment: I have attached the event to click event .. I don't think it should be working on hover..

Comment: but I am not getting message on clicking or hovering.. do you get the message?

Comment: Check answer once you are looking something like that

Comment: reportValidity() is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use syntax like

```
$('#id**^**.class')[0].setCustomValidity('**some notification string ...**');
```